# How to customize which items appear in the built-in StockTools toolbar?

Tags: highcharts

In HighStock, I'd like to use the built-in StockTools toolbar for marking up the chart, but remove some of the tools that aren't needed. I'd like to avoid building a custom toolbar ([as described in their docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools)).

I've tried variations on adjustments to

`stockTools:{ gui: { buttons: {...} } }`

and

`stockTools:{ gui: { definitions: {...} } }`

but nothing seems to hide items.

The best option I have at the moment is using CSS to hide various toolbar items but if there's a javascript-configuration option, that would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried an object but `stockTools.gui.buttons` is an array - [Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/stockTools.gui.buttons)

```
stockTools: {
  gui: {
    buttons: ['indicators', 'separator', 'simpleShapes']
  }
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1gfkoj2/)

Comment: There's an impressive amount of cursing happening over here right now. I actually did use an array (unlike what I wrote) but it was at the same level as `gui` instead of nested inside it. (－‸ლ)